# Uncaught ReferenceError: {var} is not defined. Files are created separately

Tags: javascript, jquery, document-ready

Why am I getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: i is not defined` in my javascript file?

So here's how I did it.

app.js

```
$(function() {
  var i = 1;
});
```

some.js

```
$(function() {
  alert(i);
});
```

and here's how I sequence my files.

```
// included jquery here
<script src="/app.js" type="javascript/text"></script>
<script src="/some.js" type="javascript/text"></script>
```

How can I execute or access variables from `app.js` or to other javascript files? I thought they should be listed in sequence. Where did I go wrong? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: because you are declaring a local variable `i`,not a global one, in the first block, and trying to access it in the second

Comment: It's defined, but in a local scope.

Comment: How should it be done anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is you are defining `i` in a local scope.

You should try like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var i = 1; //i in a global scope.
</script>

<script>
  alert(i);
</script>
```

There can be conflicts if you will define `i` again somewhere. So there is a better way to define namespaces to avoid conflicts like bellow.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var firstScript = {}; //this will be namespace for first script
  firstScript.i = 1;
</script>
<script>
  alert(firstScript.i);
</script>
```

Comment: By far the better answer. FWIW, a fairly typical pattern here is `var MyApp; MyApp = MyApp || {}; MyApp.property = "value"; ...` That way, load order of the scripts becomes less important. (Either script creates the `MyApp` object, or uses it if it's already there; a `var` for a variable that already exists is ingored.)